# The best way to strip out tag of multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have a form that send a **3 dimensional** array to a controller through a POST method. In that controller, I need to strip out the content of each element inside my 3D POST variable, with the php built in function `strip_tags($variable)`
What is the best solution. 
I tried the following code, but I get an empty post variable at the end:

```
$temp = array();
function stripTags($v, $k)
{
    if ($v != 'preferences' && $v != 'title'):
        $temp[$v] = strip_tags($k);
    else:
        $temp[$v] = $k;
    endif;
}
//Clean up the $_POST
if (is_array($_POST)):
    array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripTags');
    $_POST = $temp;
endif;
```

Comment: I think you can http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php array walk recursively and apply whatever functions you want including strip_tags

Comment: I tried this function, but get an empty post variable at the end, I don't know why. I update my post with the code that I have tried.

Comment: You set $temp to an empty array() at the top of the script. In your function, $temp is outside variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: The $temp  variable is outside my function, that's done on purpose, because in this case it has a global scope, to be available through all my script.

Comment: But, I think you're right, I just checked the example in the doc, I found that you have to put a keyword Global in front of the variable name inside the function to get the global scope. I was used to do that in Java, where there's no need to add a keyword to get a variable of a global scope inside a method, but it's different in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

From the strip_tags documentation comments:

```
function strip_tags_deep($value)
{
  return is_array($value) ?
    array_map('strip_tags_deep', $value) :
    strip_tags($value);
}

// Example
$array = array('<b>Foo</b>', '<i>Bar</i>', array('<b>Foo</b>', '<i>Bar</i>'));
$array = strip_tags_deep($array);

// Output
print_r($array);
```